# Struts 1.....how to set scope for multiple page in dis as how to set same list scope for /delete.do link

Tags: struts-1

```
<%@page import="com.details.EmpDetails"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Employee Details</title>
</head>
<body>

<%-- <%ArrayList<EmpDetails> a = (ArrayList<EmpDetails>)request.getAttribute("emp"); %> --%>

    <table border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Emp ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <logic:iterate id="emp" name="list">
            <tr align="center">
                <td><bean:write name="emp" property="empId"/></td>
                <td><bean:write name="emp" property="name" /></td>
                <td><bean:write name="emp" property="lname" /></td>
                <td><bean:write name="emp" property="sal" /></td>
                <td><bean:write name="emp" property="address" /></td>
                <td><form method="post">
                        <button>Edit</button>
                    </form></td>
                <td>
                    <form id="frm" action="delete.do" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="del" value=<bean:write name="emp" property="empId"/>> 
                        <input type="Submit" value="Delete">
                    </form>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </logic:iterate>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Error for this page

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find bean: "list" in any scope
```

how to set scope for multiple page in dis as how to set same list scope for /delete.do link

can u please tell any solution for this code to set list scope for overall session or application so that i can access it from anywhere

Answer (score 0):

no need to answer this question i got my answer

ANSWER
you have to use httpsession to setAttribute for whole session then we can use list anywhere in whole application